# Android Studio Emulator Not Displaying NDK hello-libs sample app - says ADB binary obsolete

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools

Trying to get an Android Studio (running Studio in Oracle Virtualbox) phone emulator working on a system with "AMD Turion" processor, 64-bit OS. Failing so far, i.e., **Android NDK hello-libs sample app does not show in emulator**. Since I have an AMD CPU vs. Intel CPU, I am getting "your CPU does not support VT-X or SVM".  An online search states I should then use an ARM-based emulator, so chose "arm64-v8a", and API level 25.  Also chose for the AVD Graphics: Software - GLES 1.1, which removed the error regarding VT-X/SVM support.  So now an emulated phone pops up, but the hello-libs app is not displaying currently.

The problem reported by Android Studio is:

> your ADB binary in Android/platform-tools is obsolete and you should update.

But, when I go to the SDK Manager it shows I have the latest Android SDK Platform Tools (version 28.0.1).

**Any ideas why Android Studio reports this error**?

Hopefully, fixing this will allow the hello-libs sample app to run/display in emulator.

(Note: I am stuck with Google API level 25 for emulation, since I have to go back several (3) Google API levels for the arm64-v8a CPU emulation).

TIA for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo ln -sf <YOUR-Android-sdk-PATH>/platform-tools/adb /usr/local/bin
```

Then use

```
adb version
```

to check your adb is the correct version.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion.  Upon further research, this error seems to be a random one (probably not important), according to google.  I will continue to look into it though.